# Table Module / Table Gateway - Where to put code for loading from gateways?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net, business-logic

Not sure if there is a "correct" answer to this, so I've flagged it as community wiki. Apologies for the long pre-amble.

I am building a modestly sized web application in .Net, and have settled on a table based architecture. My DAL layer consists of a set of TableGateway classes that handle loading/saving data to the database - these return strongly typed DataSets. Application logic is organised into a set of TableModule classes. Finally my ASPX pages handle displaying stuff and passing form values etc. to the TableModules to be worked on.

**What puzzles me is who should take responsibility for calling the TableGateway to get the DataSet, the ASPX code-behind or the TableModule?**

Example 1 - ASPX does it:

SomePage.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void AddLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        long id = long.Parse(PopulationDropDown.SelectedValue);
        string someProperty = SomePropertyTextBox.Text;

        IPopulationGateway populationGateway = DALServicesLocator.GetPopulationGateway();
        PopulationDataSet populationData = populationGateway.LoadPopulationDetails(id);

        PopulationModule.SomeLogicToAddStuff(populationData, id, someProperty);

        populationGateway.Save(populationData);
    }
```

Example 2 - TableModule does it:

SomePage.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void AddLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        long id = long.Parse(PopulationDropDown.SelectedValue);
        string someProperty = SomePropertyTextBox.Text;

        // Just pass values to the TableModule and let it talk to the Gateway.
        PopulationModule.SomeLogicToAddStuff(id, someProperty);
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate this is a trival issue in the grand scheme of things, but it's really bugging me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO 2nd variant, because it simple to split logical layers as MVC model:

- aspx page is View, only translates data and commands from and to user representation
- TableModule acts like Controller layer
- TableGateway represents Model layer

In second variant you can modify access mode in Control layer, based on internal conditions, not accessible for aspx level.
E.g. decide from which `id` really load data, check for user access rights etc.